# Python generated Excel file only shows one row of data vs multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to write the results from the loop into an Excel file (keys = column names) and (values = rows data). This code generates the file for me, but it only prints one row of data in the file. How can i make it append the other rows to the file?

```
import pandas as pd


p = (('BusinessName', 'CustomerNameToSearch'), ('PageSize', '2'), ('CountryCode', 'CA'))
prepare_link = requests.get('https://api.myapiloopuplink?', auth=BearerAuth('PMay4TY5K577b76154i97yC9DlbPytqd'), params=p)
test = requests.get(prepare_link.url, auth=BearerAuth('PMay4TY5K577b76154i97yC9DlbPytqd'), params=p)

data = json.loads(test.text)

CustomerIdList = []
for customer in data['Data']:

    
    BusinessID = customer['BusinessId']
    BusinessName = customer['BusinessName']
    CustomerIdList.append(str(customer['BusinessId']))

    
    
    for i in CustomerIdList:

        links2 = ("https://api.myapiloopuplink/"+i+"/History?count=1")
        test2 = requests.get(links2, auth=BearerAuth('PMay4TY5K577b76154i97yC9DlbPytqd'))
        data2 = json.loads(test2.text)

         
        start_row = 0
        for extradetails in data2['Data']:
            
            myDict = {}
            myDict["BusinessId"] = customer['BusinessId']
            myDict["BusinessName"] = customer['BusinessName']
            myDict["Year"] = extradetails['Year']
            myDict["Rate"] = extradetails['Rate']
            print(myDict)
            
            k = list(myDict.keys())
            v = list(myDict.values())
            
            #print(k)
            #print(v)
  
            
            x = [myDict]
            df = pd.DataFrame(x)
            df.to_excel ('locationandnameoffile.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1', index = False, startrow=start_row)
            start_row = start_row + len(df) + 1
```

This is the output i currently get

[image]

This is the output i am trying to get

[image]

In the loop i get the right results when i print (it shows multiple rows)

```
print(myDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
for extradetails in data2['Data']:
            
            myDict = {}
            myDict["BusinessId"] = customer['BusinessId']
            myDict["BusinessName"] = customer['BusinessName']
            myDict["Year"] = extradetails['Year']
            myDict["Rate"] = extradetails['Rate']
            print(myDict)
            
            k = list(myDict.keys())
            v = list(myDict.values())
            
            #print(k)
            #print(v)
  
            
            x = [myDict]
            df = pd.DataFrame(x) #problem
            df.to_excel ('locationandnameoffile.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1', index = False, startrow=start_row)#problem
            start_row = start_row + len(df) + 1
```

You are creating an excel file in every loop. How about create an excel file after the loop completes. like this:

```
        datas=[]
        for extradetails in data2['Data']:
            
            myDict = {}
            myDict["BusinessId"] = customer['BusinessId']
            myDict["BusinessName"] = customer['BusinessName']
            myDict["Year"] = extradetails['Year']
            myDict["Rate"] = extradetails['Rate']
            print(myDict)
            
            k = list(myDict.keys())
            v = list(myDict.values())
            
            #print(k)
            #print(v)
  
            
            datas.append([myDict])
            start_row = start_row + len(df) + 1
        df = pd.DataFrame(datas)
        df.to_excel ('locationandnameoffile.xlsx', sheet_name = 'sheet1', index = False, startrow=start_row)
```